How to Identify and Terminate Idle tmux Sessions on a Debian Server
I have a Debian server with multiple tmux sessions running. Some of these sessions are idle and not running any active processes. How can I identify and terminate all tmux sessions that are not currently running any processes or commands? Additionally, what command can I use to kill all of these idle sessions at once? Detailed steps or commands would be greatly appreciated.

Define "idle" and/or "active process". Is an unattached session with a window with a pane with a shell waiting for commands idle? Is a pane running tail -f /dev/null idle? Or is only a session where in each pane the main process is dead idle? (remain-on-exit on). How about a pane with the main process dead, but where (grand)children still use their controlling terminal provided by the pane?

Idle is not running any command or being empty

Please be specific. There is a difference between a pane not running any command and a pane running an interactive shell not running any command. Does the latter qualify as idle?

what do you mean with interactive shell and i want windows not panes
